# How do I fix the attribute error in python?

Tags: python, graphics, zelle-graphics

I'm new to python and I'm currently learning objects and graphics. I imported the graphics.py file successfully but for some reason it keeps giving me an attribute error whenever I try to run `GraphWin`. please see below:

```
import graphics
win = graphics.GraphWin()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'graphics' has no attribute 'GraphWin'
```

I'm using Zelle's "Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science" and it's been helpful.

please advise.

Comment: Wild guess: You called your own file `graphics.py` and now it's importing itself.

Comment: @Matthias when i downloaded the file it was initially saved as _init_. i had trouble importing the file until i saved it in the lib folder of the python program. then i got the attribute error and i renamed the file to "graphics", but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is the graphics.py in the same as the file you’re getting the error in?

Also, try
`from graphics import *` 
Instead of
`import graphics`

Comment: i saved the graphics.py in its own folder called "graphics" in the Lib folder of the python program. the problem is that the GraphWin attribute can't be executed. however, if i double-click the same graphics file it runs normally. also, i tried your suggestion but it gives me the same error.

Comment: I’ve never used graphics but according to this the graphics.py and your file need to be in the same folder. 

anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/graphics.html

Answer (score 0):

i checked out [this article](https://www.codespeedy.com/handle-an-attribute-error-in-python/#:%7E:text=An%20attribute%20error%20occurs%20when%20the%20Python%20interpreter,very%20simple%20and%20basic%20example%20of%20this%20is.) and it proved helpful. i just had to create an extension where i added the specific sub-module to the module folder. in this case it's:

```
from graphics._init_ import *
win = GraphWin()
```

this solves the attribute error. however, it only works with the from  import * formula and not the import  formula

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

> pip install graphics.py